# Apache Spark 2 broadcast variable deserialization

Tags: apache-spark, deserialization, broadcast

I have Spark 2.2.0 and I have some problems. I have to use broadcast variable which has 300MB and it seems that it is deserializing for every task and that cause performance issues. Is there some possibility to ensure that  deserializing will be only once per executor?

```
val b=sc.broadcast(myLargeDataObj)
val c=x.map {(r:org.apache.spark.sql.Row) => b.value.getDataFromMyLargeDataObj(r.getLong(0))} .collect
```

Thanks.

**Comment reaction:**

I tried to profile remote spark using jmx and I saw that lot of cpu is used for serialization and deserialization and for example in attached   details for stage is shown that time for deserialization is significant.

[image]

My spark configuration is standard for cloudera distribution 5.12.1. I use spark-shell(2.2.0) and I have 1 driver and 2 executors, 4G is set for driver and  executors by arguments, YARN is master and I have Java 1.8. Serializer is Kryo.

Comment: @user8371915 I updated question